code from leetcode book wrong or am I adding up the answer wrong?
Given an integer array nums and an integer k, find the number of subarrays whose sum is equal to k.
The solution they gave to this problem (includes negative numbers)
var subarraySum = function(nums, k) {
    let counts = new Map();
    counts.set(0, 1);
    let ans = 0, curr = 0;

    for (const num of nums) {
        curr += num;
        ans += counts.get(curr - k) || 0;
        counts.set(curr, (counts.get(curr) || 0) + 1);
    }

    return ans;
};

I then gave an input of [-3,6,-3,6,-3] and k= 3, but it returns 5 instead of 4.   It just so happens that the Map contains key=0, count=2 and adding that 2 in messes things up.  I was really trying to understand this maintaining counts of total sums by trying varying arrays.
thanks!
There example of [1, 2, 1, 2, 1] and k=3 works but then I changed it to negatives since that is supposed to be possible.
I am trying to figure out why we care about keeping track of how many times things add up to 0, things add up to 1, things add up to x.  I thought we only care about how many things add up to k(and in this case, k=3).

Why should it return 4? The subarrays are -3,6, 6,-3, -3,6, 6,-3 and -3,6,-3,6,-3. Ie there are 5 subarrays whicb sum up to -3

yes, you are right.  I realized that is what is different and now I understand the counts map too. thanks.

Here is my solution.
const subarraySum = function (nums, k) {
    let sum = 0;
    let res = 0;
    let freq = new Map();
    nums.push(0);

    for (let num of nums) {
        let need = sum - k;
        if (freq.has(need)) {
            res += freq.get(need);
        }

        if (freq.has(sum)) {
            freq.set(sum, freq.get(sum) + 1);
        } else {
            freq.set(sum, 1);
        }

        sum += num;
    }

    return res;
};

Example
Let's say nums = [1, 2, 3] and k = 3.
Initialize: sum = 0, res = 0, freq = {}, and nums = [1, 2, 3, 0].
Iterate through nums:

For num = 1: need = sum - k = 0 - 3 = -3 (not in freq). Update freq:
{0: 1} (cumulative sum 0 has been seen once). Update sum: sum = sum +
num = 0 + 1 = 1.

For num = 2:
need = sum - k = 1 - 3 = -2 (not in freq).
Update freq: {0: 1, 1: 1} (cumulative sum 1 has been seen once).
Update sum: sum = sum + num = 1 + 2 = 3.

For num = 3:
need = sum - k = 3 - 3 = 0 (in freq, count is 1).
Add to res: res = res + freq[0] = 0 + 1 = 1.
Update freq: {0: 1, 1: 1, 3: 1} (cumulative sum 3 has been seen once).
Update sum: sum = sum + num = 3 + 3 = 6.

For num = 0:
need = sum - k = 6 - 3 = 3 (in freq, count is 1).
Add to res: res = res + freq[3] = 1 + 1 = 2.
Update freq: {0: 1, 1: 1, 3: 1, 6: 1} (cumulative sum 6 has been seen once).
Update sum: sum = sum + num = 6 + 0 = 6.

The final result res = 2 indicates that there are 2 subarrays that sum to k: [1, 2] and [3].


